# How to make bootstrap navbar smoothly toggle in chrome from right to left on small screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to toggle bootstrap navabar from right to left instead of top to bottom.I acheived this with following code-

HTML-

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" style="height: 55px; padding-top: 2px; background-color: #000;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="a_logo_s_s">
                        <img src="images/Png - Only Logo - Variant 2.png"  class="img-responsive" id="logo_s_s" >
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="a_logo_l_s">
                        <img src="images/Png - Only Text - White.png" class="img-responsive" id="logo_l_s" >
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" style="height: 346px !important">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li class="active" id="l_hiw"><a href="#s3" id="hiw" class="navLink">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                        <li id="l_cp"><a href="#s4_1" id="cp" class="navLink">COACHES</a></li>
                        <li id="l_cp"><a href="#s5" id="au" class="navLink">ABOUT</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li id="l_el"><a href="#" id="el">ENROLL</a></li>
                        <li id="l_ma"><a href="#" id="ma" class="navLink">MANAGE ACCOUNT</a></li>
                        <li id="l_aq"><a href="#cftr" id="aq" class="navLink">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


</nav>
```

CSS-

```
.is_open{
    width: 240px;
}
#myNavbar{
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS-

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click',function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();

        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#myNavbar").css({
            "height":"100%",
            });
        },10);

        $("#myNavbar").toggleClass('is_open',1000);

 });
```

It is working fine for first 15-20 clicks then it behaves like this-

1. on first click does't happen anything.
2. on secod click navbar appears for a moment and then disappears, means both first and second click are called simultaneaously.

Edit 1:
I have used "right" property of css,"transform" property of css, "animate" function of jQuery, in which first and second takes values 0 and -240px on alternate clicks which shows a very little jerk while showing and hiding, this is happening only in chrome, working fine in other browsers.
Animate is following the behaviour described above on 1., 2., it is happening in all browsers.

Edit 2:
I added

```
       setTimeout(function(){
            $("#myNavbar").css({
            "height":"100%",
            });
        },10);
```

in javascript because height of navbar goes to 1px while hiding, and thus slide effect to left becomes invisible, slide to left effect is, only visible after adding "setTimeout" without this it behaves as if height is not set to 100%.
Even I have hardcoded "height: 100%" in style attribute of navbar but still it gets overriden with "height:1px" after first click.So to keep height:100%,I found only possible way and that was to assign it value after every click.

That also may be the reason for slight jerk in showing and hiding beacuse height is changing from 1px -> 100% ->346px as I observed it in chrome console.Also,
this is happening in chrome only.

Comment: Is it at all possible to toggle the bootstrap navbar smoothly from right to left in chrome? If so, please explain your way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to achieve a smoother animation

```
$(function(){
    var c=0;
    $(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
        $("#myNavbar").stop().animate({right:2*100 }, 'slow');
    });  
});
```

Example

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvZqwM

Comment: in your case navbar returns amid on another click, i have used stop() too, but I am still not getting that effect.

Comment: I updated the codepen, tell me if it's what you need

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved and it had flaws like-

1. Custom css file was added before bootstrap css, that made browser to override custom css by bootstrap css,no matter how many times we define the style of an element in html or css.This also makes possible to declare height only once and thus getting rid of setTimeout(expandHeight,10) on every click.
2. **.stop()** (stop function) should be there before .animate (animation function) so that it can prevent previous ongoing animation otherwise browser will produce glitches.
3. **.collapse** was defined in bootstrap with **block:none** that made navbar unvisible (as navbar also had a class "collapse") after a click becuase custom css didn't have such declarations.

and thanks to Ovidiu Unguru